# PHP: Getting the time for a specific timezone, which can't be changed by the system owner

Tags: php, time, timezone

I've got a question for you guys. I'm currently creating some kind of license system, written in PHP. And of course, this has to be a secure system, and the license should be checked in many different ways. I ran into a problem when I need to check the expiration date.

Basically, I want to get the current time of a timezone (GMT +1). However, I must be sure that this time is the real time, and can't be changed by the owner of the software. If the license expires, the owner shouldn't be able to change the clock on the server, or do something else that could make the license valid again.

I was thinking about checking with my server, like sending a cURL request and check the given time from there - because it can't be edited by someone else. In that case, the owner could just IP-block my domain/ip, and his server won't connect to check the current time. Of course, I could "end the license" when my website isn't responding the last 10 times. But if I get DDoSed/attacked, it shouldn't affect a good customer, of course?

So, is there any way, in PHP, to get the current "world clock" in GMT +1? And the owner of the server must in ANY WAY not be able to change the clock.

Ideas? Code examples?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The code is encrypted so they wont have access to the source code, only the encrypted one.

Answer (score 1):

PHP always uses the system clock that can be changed by the system administrator. You could use a NTP Service or a world clock WebService to get the current world-time, but therefore you have to have a internet connection - and as you said it *could* be manipulated.

Another thougt: As a server administrator you would probably not manipulate the system clock on a production server to avoid a license to expire, beause correct server time is critical to many applications including network filesystems and authentication.

If the client does not have/can manipulate the source code you could log the system time on a regular basis e.g. to a database or encrypted file and calculate the runtime based on the firstrun and check for time-changes that are significant.

Comment: I agree with you. They [probably] wont change the timezone/clock. But it is still [possible] for them to do. I want to eliminate all the risks and make this license checker 100% trusted by me. Any ideas? I have also updated my first post, the client doesn't have access to the source code. Only the encrypted source, which can't be modified.

Comment: Feels like that isn't a smart solution, I'm sorry. Any other thoughts?

Comment: No problem. But you will need some sort of indicator for manipulation and a trusted source - IMO you will not find any system service that is reliable enough to fit these requirements.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was hoping there was a smart and small solution for this. But probably, there isnt. :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the short answer is, that it is not possible to do what you are trying to do.

Your client has access to the server ( known by the statements that he can change the server clock, and block your host ).

This means your client can modify your sourcecode or jump through arbitrary hoops to throw away your licensing.

Which in PHP leaves you with trying to make it difficult to tamper with your code.

You could of course use some sort of obfuscation tools, and handle it that way.

My advice though is to trust your clients, and let them have your sourcecode, as you're going to give that to them any way, and then just not push updates or fixes to users without a license.

If you need more monetization be sure to bill your support hours, and the such.

Spend your time coding the features, not the DRM, get the better product, and your clients will happily pay you!

I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: The owner does not have the source code, only encrypted source code. I have updated my first post. Any advice?